# actionscript 3 contentHeight not updating properly

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder4.5

I am using Adobe Flash Builder with actionscript to make a desktop application.
I am getting some html code from a webpage and putting it into an mx:html element, then attempting to get the content height in order to determine if I should hide the vertical scrollbar or not. However, when using contentHeight it seems to return the height of the previous state of the element, rather than the one just set.

This is the code to fetch the html page

```
var htmlPageRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url); 
htmlPageRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.GET; //set request's html request method to GET

htmlPageLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onHtmlLoaded); //listen for page load
htmlPageLoader.load(htmlPageRequest);//when loaded continue logic in new function
```

This is the function that is run when the page request is complete

```
private function onHtmlLoaded(e:Event):void { //logic after html page has loaded 
            HtmlElement.data = htmlPageLoader.data; //set content

            //determine if vscroll bar should be visible
            if(HtmlElement.contentHeight > HtmlElement.height) {
                scrollbar.visible = true; 
            }
            else {
                scrollbar.visible = false;
            }

            trace(HtmlElement.height);
            trace(HTMLELEMENT.contentHeight);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have realised the solution to the problem:

```
htmlElement.data = htmlPageLoader.data;
```

Rendering the HTML takes a certain amount of time - the contentHeight is being accessed before the page has actually rendered, causing the previous value to be returned.
In order to fix this, I added an event listener for (htmlRender) in order to not access contentHeight until the rendering is complete.

```
private function onHtmlLoaded(e:Event):void { //logic after html page has loaded 

        htmlElement.addEventListener(Event.HTML_RENDER, onHtmlRendered); //once the html has rendered, move on
        htmlElement.data = htmlPageLoader.data; //render content                
        }

        private function onHtmlRendered(e:Event):void { //logic for after the page has rendered

            //if the content of the HTML element is bigger than the box, show the scrollbar
            if(htmlElement.contentHeight > htmlElement.height) {
                scrollbar.visible = true; 
            }
            else {
                scrollbar.visible = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: mark this as right answer so this question will be viewed as useful for preceders.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using a `URLLoader` (`htmlPageLoader`) instance here to load the webpage into the `mx:HTML` element, which may not be actually required.

The `mx:HTML` component actually provides an inbuilt way to load an webpage into itself. This can be done using the `location` property of the `mx:HTML` class. It expects a simple string which could be the URL of your webpage you are trying to load.

Once the webpage is loaded, the `Event.COMPLETE` method is fired, within which you should be able to get your content height properly. So please try the following code:

```
htmlElement.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onHtmlLoaded);
htmlElement.location = "your URL goes here";

private function onHtmlLoaded(e:Event):void 
{  
    htmlElement.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onHtmlLoaded);
    trace(htmlElement.contentHeight);
}
```

I've tried the above with a couple of URL's and it seems to be working fine. Also, I took the liberty of using camel case naming convention for `htmlElement`. It's just best practice.

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: The reason I didn't use the inbuilt method as I did not want the previous content to be de-rendered before the new HTML was downloaded. You're correct, I am using an URLLoader for it (I forgot to include that). My apologies about the camel case - I did a typo in my find/replace when renaming to something that makes sense in this context.

Comment: @darthmorf I understand. I have seen your answer below and am glad that you were able to solve it. Thanks.